# ファイルをステージ状態にしたいのですができません

Tags: git

現在、Gitを用いてローカルリポジトリを中央リポジトリに同期させる練習をしているのですが、作成したファイルをステージ状態にするところで苦戦をしております。

IDLEを用いて作成したhangman.pyというファイルを、コマンドプロンプトのhangmanディレクトリに移動させたのですが(ただ、私がそう認識しているだけであり本当は移動できていないかもしれません)、そこからどうやってステージ状態にするかが分かりません。ぜひプロフェッショナルの皆様からお力を貸していただきたいです。

「独学プログラマー」の本によれば、ステージング状態にするには、コマンドプロンプトにおいて
`git status` と実行すれば以下のように表示されて成功するはずなのです。

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with...(省略)
```

しかし実際には以下のメッセージが表示されてしまいます。どうすればよいのでしょうか？

```
On branch master
No commits yet
nothing to commit(create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git status` はリポジトリの「状態」を確認するコマンドです。ファイルをステージング状態にするにはメッセージにも出ている通り
`git add FILENAME` を実行してください。